# Managing User Profiles with PHP/MySQL for Beginners

Tags: php, mysql, user-profile

I am beginner in PHP/MySql and would develop a simple site that has user management. I like the idea of using OpenId's (like stackoverflow uses).

I wonder from where to start? What should I read?

I have not much time so probably will net enter in all details of PHP user session management, this because I search something like ***User profiles management in PHP for dummies*** 8D

Environment:

> Linux OS
>   Apache 2.2.15
>   MySQL 5.1.41
>   PHP   5.2.13
>
> cPanel    11.25.0

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise not to start from using OpenID, as it would be harder than usual way with storing login and pass in the local database. You can implement OpenID later.
Start from designing a database. Then search SO for `PHP Authentication` for examples and finally take a look at [PHP session management](http://php.net/session).
And sorry, but lack of time is not an excuse. If you have basic database knowledge, user profile management is not harder than any other data menagement. If you don't - better start to learn it.

Comment: I agree, lack of time is not an excuse. Just want to know from where to start.